# How to set origin of matlab plot at center?

Tags: matlab

I tried to plot a piecewise function in matlab.

```
syms x
y = piecewise(-1<x<0, x^2+2*x, 0<=x<1, 0);
fplot(y)
```

[image]

as the plot came is correct but visually its no good.

I want to set its origin at the center of the plot. How to do it?

Comment: Hi Joey, please consider revisiting your previous questions and marking the answer that solves your question as [accepted](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) by clicking  `✓` on the left side of the answer. You can also [upvote](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/173400) all the helpful answers if you like once you reach 15 reputation points by clicking `▲` on the left side of the answers.

Answer (score 4):

1. Set same minimum and maximum space on both sides of the origin.

   ```
   ax = gca;
   MaxX = max(abs(ax.XLim));    MaxY = max(abs(ax.YLim));
   axis([-MaxX MaxX -MaxY MaxY]);
   ```
2. If you also want (psuedo)-axis lines at origin, you may further use:

   ```
   xline(0,'--');  yline(0,'--');    %requires R2018b
   ```

   But if you actually want to move the axis location to origin then you may use the properties
   [`XAxisLocation`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.axis.axes-properties.html#budumk7-XAxisLocation) and [`YaxisLocation`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.axis.axes-properties.html#budumk7-YAxisLocation) instead of pseudo axis lines.

   ```
   ax.XAxisLocation='origin';   ax.YAxisLocation='origin';
   ```